# How to make the orbit space $T/G$ of torus $T$ homeomorphic to the Klein bottle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Actually it is one of the exercises of [Munkres](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292). $G$ is a group of homeomorphisms of the torus having order $2$. 
How do I get $G$ in order to make $T/G$ homeomorphic to the Klein bottle? Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: If the torus is $S^1\times S^1$, what are obvious self-homeomorphisms of $S^1$ of order $2$?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567304/klein-bottle-covered-by-the-torus?rq=1 and links listed there.